# What language / library should I use for transforming XML & replacing tag names

Tags: xml

I'm working with multiple XML data feeds [that are large files], and I will eventually be putting all of the data from the XML files into a MySQL database; however, I want to be able to use only 1 table for all of the XML files (that, when raw, have different tag names). So basically, I want to know what language would be most efficient for parsing the XML files, and create a new file of which has replaced all X tags with Y tags.

Comment: You are looking for XSLT